# How to get content_scripts to execute in file:/// URLs in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't seem to make this work no matter what I do. Let me demonstrate with a very simple example extension. Here is the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sample Of Content Script",
  "description": "Changes the background of a page pink",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js": [ "changer.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  }
}
```

Notice that my `content_scripts` entry matches `all_urls`, which (according to [Google documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)) should match `file:///` URLs.

The `background.js`:

```
(function (chrome) {
    'use strict';

    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function (details) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(details.tabId, {
            action: 'changeBackground',
            color: 'pink'
        });
    });

})(chrome);
```

And the `changer.js` (content script):

```
(function (chrome) {
    'use strict';

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
        if (request.action !== 'changeBackground') { return; }
        document.body.style.background = request.color;
    });

})(chrome);
```

This extension has been published on the Chrome Web Store so you can see the result in action:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sample-of-content-script/bkekbfjgkkineeokljnobgcoadlhdckd

It's a pretty simple extension. Navigate to a page, and it turn's the page's background pink. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for any `file:///` URLs. The `changer.js` script is not loaded into the page, and nothing happens.

## Extra info

- It actually **seems** to work just fine when running as an *Unpacked extension* in *Developer mode*. Pages loaded from the file system turn pink.
- I tried using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` instead of putting the script into the manifest. This failed in a more obvious way, saying that I didn't request permissions to modify `file:///` URLs in the manifest.
- I added `"file:///*/*"` to the `permissions` section of `manifest.json`. That seemed to workwell with `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`, but the Chrome Web Store rejected the extension, saying that `file:///` permissions are not allowed.
- I reverted to a `content_script` section in `manifest.json` and tried adding `"file:///*/*` to the `matches` section in the manifest. Again, this worked in a development build, but when I uploaded it to the Chrome Web Store and then installed it, it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<all_urls>` indeed covers `file://` scheme, but it must be manually activated in the extensions list.

If an extension has permissions that cover `file://` scheme, it will have a checkbox "Allow access to file URLs" next to "Allow in incognito". The user must enable that manually; you can help by creating a tab with preconfigured URL, after explaining the process:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://extensions/?id=" + chrome.runtime.id});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice that detail.

Comment: Yep, this can be confusing, since extension icon is colored and says that "ExtensionName has access to this site" - even though the manual option in extension's detail is off x) I would consider this even a bug of the status icon.